# How can an object be created without calling the constructor in C++?

Tags: c++

The following program is in 5 files. The output is 0  32, instead of 14  32 and therefore an object is constructed without calling the constructor. How is this possible?

character.h:

```
#ifndef CHARACTER_H
#define CHARACTER_H 

class Character
{
public:
    Character() {}

    class Settings
    {
    public:
        int size_;
        Settings():
            size_(14)
        {}
    };
    const static Settings DEFAULT_SETTINGS;
};

#endif // CHARACTER_H
```

character.cpp:

```
#include "character.h"

const Character::Settings Character::DEFAULT_SETTINGS;
```

word.h

```
#ifndef WORD_H
#define WORD_H

#include <iostream>

#include "character.h"

class Word 
{
public:
    Word() {}

    class Settings
    {
    public:
        Character::Settings characterSettings_;
        int length_;

        Settings():
            length_(32)
        {
            characterSettings_ = Character::DEFAULT_SETTINGS;
        }
    };

    static const Settings DEFAULT_SETTINGS;

    void write(Settings settings = DEFAULT_SETTINGS) // this default parameter is 
                                                     // constructed without a   
                                                     // constructor call
    {
        std::cout << settings.characterSettings_.size_ << std::endl;
        std::cout << settings.length_ << std::endl;
     }
 };

#endif // WORD_H
```

word.cpp

```
#include "word.h"

const Word::Settings Word::DEFAULT_SETTINGS;
```

main.cpp

```
#include "word.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Word member;
    member.write();
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: As an aside, you should `return 0` from `main()` on success and `return` something else (usually `1`) on failure.

Comment: As an aside to @JonPurdy aside. When you only ever indicate success it is perfectly valid to not return anything from `main()`. This is the equivalent to `return 0`.

Comment: Falling off `main` being equivalent to `return 0;` is only in C++ not in C. (yes, I'm aware this is a C++ question, but it's good to know!). On the other hand, C programs are allowed to recurse by calling `main`, from itself or elsewhere; this is not defined in C++. Trivia, trivia ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's called the *static initialization fiasco*. Basically there is no fixed order on the execution of the constructors for variables with static duration defined in different translation units. In this particular case the `Word::DEFAULT_SETTINGS` has been constructed before the `Character::DEFAULT_SETTINGS` and thus has read the `0` value that variables of static duration have before being actually initialized. If you want to see something interesting, dump the contents of `Character::DEFAULT_SETTINGS` and you will see that *strangely* enough it is `14`

Comment: Thank you! I was really hopeless about this. Please is there a workaround?

Comment: The simplest one is that variables with static duration should never depend on other variables with static duration. In general you should avoid having them altogether, if there is a *very good* reason for them, you can change the paradigm to use functions that return a *local* object with *static* duration (to ensure order of initialization), but there is no good solution to the problem other than redesigning.

Comment: It seems that this is a common problem: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ctors.html#faq-10.15

Comment: @MartinDrozdik: This is a good read. [How do I prevent static Initialization Fiasco?](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ctors.html#faq-10.17)

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I will keep your words in mind!

Answer (score 1):

The static initialization order problem can be solved with some clever (not really) header file tricks.

Basically the gist of the idea is this (and I have implemented it in practice, several times, though eons ago, so this is not just some idle Stack Overflow idea of the moment):

Basically, you put the definition of the static object, like `foo_class g_foo;` in a specially delimited area of your `foo.h` header file:

```
#ifndef FOO_H
#define FOO_H

#include "bar.h"  // dependency: crucial part!

// ... declares foo_class ...

// foo is a client of bar

// Now somewhere near the bottom:

#ifdef DEFINE_GLOBAL_SINGLETONS
foo_class g_foo;
#endif
```

Now you set up a specially designated singleton repository source file, where you include all the headers.

```
// singletons.cc
#define DEFINE_GLOBAL_SINGLETONS
#include "foo.h"
#include "bar.h"  // note deliberately wrong order!
```

The header file include dependencies and guards will cause the headers to be included in the module dependency order, and thus the `DEFINE_GLOBAL_SINGLETONS` sections to be added to the translation unit in the proper order.

Within a single translation unit, C++ requires the objects to be constructed top to bottom.

So you get Ada/Modula like module initialization order: used module before user. `foo` users `bar` and soo the  `bar` singleton, if any, is initialized before the `foo` one.

Now the downside: recompiling the singleton repository every time a header changes.